# How to determine whether a differential $1$-form is globally welldefined?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

This is a question that occurred after working on finding a generator of the first de Rham cohomology group of the torus. It was pointed out to me that the differential $1$-form

$$ dx + dy$$

was well defined on all of $T$ and that this is generally not the case.

Hence my question(s):

> (1) Given a differential form, how do I find out whether it is
>   globally well defined or only locally?
>
> (2) In this concrete example how can I prove that $dx + dy$ is well
>   defined on $T$?

Since the two questions seem so closely related I posted them in one question but if this is inappropriate please leave a comment and I will split them into two separate quetions.

Comment: What are $d x$ and $d y$?

Comment: @ZhenLin Two differential $1$-forms. I'm not sure what you mean... could you ask more explicitly?

Comment: Can you _describe_ them? It's not obvious what you mean!

Comment: @ZhenLin Ok, give me a moment, I need to think for some time.

Comment: @ZhenLin Ok, I have a description now: $x$ and $y$ are coordinates for the torus, which is $S^1 \times S^1$ so $x,y$ are both the angle in $S^1$ and $dx,dy$ are a basis for the tangent space of the torus (at any point). The only thing that's bothering me with this is that the tangent plane should be different at each point but since $x,y$ are global coordinates it seems that the tangent vectors are point independent...

Comment: That's not quite correct, but the point is that $x$ and $y$ are well defined up to an additive constant, so their differentials are well defined everywhere.

Comment: @ZhenLin I am trying to prove it. If $T = S^1 \times S^1$ is parameterized by $(x,y) = (e^{1\phi}, e^{i\theta)}$ where $\phi, \theta \in [0,2\pi]$ then how would I calculate $dx$?

Answer (score 3):

Take T to be the quotient space of $\pi:\ \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2$, where $\mathbb{Z}^2$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by the translations $t_{mn}: (x,y)\mapsto(x+m,y+n)$ for arbitrary integers $m$ and $n$. Those actions obviously leaves $dx$ and $dy$ unchanged:  $$t_{mn}^*(dx)=d(x+m)=dx,\ t_{mn}^*(dy)=d(y+n)=dy$$
And if $\tilde X$ is the lift up of a vector field $X$ on T, that is, for any $q=\pi(p)$, $\pi_*(\tilde X_p)=X_q$, and $z$ is another point in the pre-image of $q$ (that is $\pi(z)=q$ too), and $t$ is an action maps $p$ to $z$, we have $\pi_* (t_*(\tilde X_p))=\pi_*(\tilde X_p)$.

Thus $dx$ and $dy$ are well-defined on the quotient space T, since, for any form $\tilde\omega$ preserved by deck transformations $t$ (that is $t^*\tilde\omega=\tilde\omega$), we can always push down it to a form $\omega$ on the quotient space like:
$$\omega_q(X_q)=\tilde\omega_p(\tilde X_p)$$ This $\omega$ is well defined for if we  lift up $X$ to a different point $z$ (where $\pi(z)=q$ and $t(p)=z$) we have:
$$\tilde\omega_z(\tilde X_z)=t^*(\tilde\omega_z)(\tilde X_p)=\tilde\omega_p(\tilde X_p)$$

Comment: Thank you, this really helps me. What is the map $t^\ast_{mn}$?

Comment: pull back of t_mn

Comment: Thank you. I will need some time to study your answer before I accept because there are a few new concepts in it that I need to understand.